# Compare each of the elements of a list with another one

Tags: python, list, loops

How can I iterate or loop through each of the elements of a list with another list?

If I use the following:

```
"for m, e in zip (arrayMaster, arrayExamples):"
```

I get a - A, b - B, c - C

I pretend to get this: a - A, a - B, a - C, b - A, b - B, b - C....

My ultimate goal is to compare two lists and if the characters in list "e" are found in list "m" it will output a True message.

Example:

```
List m

Sbh 411,
Sbh 25 Str,
Sba 3 Str Sba 3 Str,
A 203,
Sbh 611,
Sbm 800,
O 19 MozartWA,
BUS BusoniF Sbm 800 Kin,
Sbb 2 Sch,
Sbb 2 Men,
Sbc 22,
Sbc 21,
Sbh 9,
Sbc 31 Ede,
Sbc 22 Hey,
...

List e

Sba 1,
Sba 2,
Sba 3,
Sba 4,
Sba 5,
Sba 6,
Sba 7,
Sba 8,
Sba 9,
Sba 10,
Sba 11,
Sba 12,
Sba 13,
Sba 14,
Sba 15,
Sba 16,
Sba 17,
...
```

Comment: if `Sba 1` is there in the list e and m  = `[Sba 411]`, Then  should the output be [True] or [False]?

Answer (score 1):

No need to iterate through each elements, just use the built-in `in`:

```
for i, m in enumerate(arrayMaster):
    if m in arrayExamples:
        print(f'arrayMaster index: {i}')
        print(f'arrayExamples index: {arrayExamples.index(m)}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think I expressed myself badly, sorry, I would like to check which is the exact element that match between the lists and for that if I need to go through each one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be

```
for m in M:
    if m in E:
        print(m, True)
```